# js functionality for onclick button through html tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I am trying to write to call the js functionality in my select button by using this syntax...

```
<button onclick="UversePlanSelector()">Select</button>
```

but its not working fine.
Can you tell me how to fix it?
Providing my code below:

```
<div id="wrap_plans">
        
        <div class="plan">
            <div class="plan_head"><span class="hdr">Power</span><span class="tag">$64.95</span>
            </div>
            <div class="plan_spec"><span class="hdr">45 / 8</span> Mbps</div>
            <button onclick="UversePlanSelector()">Select</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is that function global?

Comment: Not the main issue but you cannot use the `in` property freely like that cause it's a `reserved word` so wrap with quotes:`this.sel = {'in': -1, tv: -1}` and sq. brackets: `this.sel['in'] = -1;` Also what should this line do? `while (e = e.offsetParent) {` you meant `===`. Also use strict equality while comparing with `0` ... at best use it always: `ix === 0`, `a === b`

Comment: Also if your JS code has more than 30 lines (and it has `:)` ) make sure to explain where to look, what's not working exactly, what's the expected result and more additional hints.

Answer (score 1):

First, UversePlanSelector was not in the global object

From:

```
function UversePlanSelector(wrap, plans_in, plans_tv) {...
// > ReferenceError: UversePlanSelector is not defined
```

To:

```
UversePlanSelector = function UversePlanSelector(wrap, plans_in, plans_tv) {...
```

Seccond, UversePlanSelector is a constructor

From:

```
<button onclick="UversePlanSelector()">Select</button>
// > Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'init'
```

To:

```
<button onclick="new UversePlanSelector()">Select</button>
```

Third, UversePlanSelector takes 3 arguments, none of them given

Declaration:

```
UversePlanSelector = function UversePlanSelector(wrap, plans_in, plans_tv) {...
```

Call:

```
<button onclick="new UversePlanSelector( /* No args given */ )">Select</button>
```

Consecuence:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Probably in plans_in but I think that you should be who debugs it further :-)

Answer (score 0):

The jsfiddle will wrap all js code into a function, and that's why your html cannot see. To fix that just assign your function to a variable, like the below:

```
window.f = function() {...} //instead of function f() {...}
```

Check the [updated fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/Cs8kh/32/)